# Vue - Pass Rules Array to Child Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am currently passing a set of props, "propSet", to a child component.  The props are computed and detect an 'edit mode' boolean and change accordingly.

"propSet" defines the following form input props: color, filled, dense, outlined, readonly, required, and *rules*.

All the props work, except for "rules".  I receive the following error message in the console every time a child component uses the 'editMode == true' configuration of "propSet":

> [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "rules". Expected
> Array, got Object

I have tried quite a few things, but in particular, I've tried to:

- Add type validation to the Child Component for the rules array

  - `props: ['propSet'] //original`
  - `props: { propSet: Array } //updated`
- Utilized Object.entries() to change the object to an array

  - `var rulesSet = Object.entries(this.rules)`
- Change rules - tried to configure the rules several different ways

  - ```
     //original  
     rules: {
        required: (v) => !!v || "This field is required",
        autoComplete: (v) => !!(v && v.length) || "This field is required",
      },
    ```
  - ```
     //updated
     rules: [{
       required: (v) => !!v || "This field is required"},{
       autoComplete: (v) => !!(v && v.length) || "This field is required",
      }],
    ```

I've read the documentation for Props several times, and I haven't seen an answer to my issue there (unless I'm overlooking it).  I've also read the documentation I could find related to the rules array in the Vuetify API.

I've also read quite a few SO questions related to Vue.js, props, and components.

I think I might just be missing something very obvious.

Here is a codepen with a different set of props for brevity's sake, which demonstrates the problem:

[Pass-Rules-As-Prop](https://codepen.io/dhurken/pen/XWepxJx?editors=1111)

Answer (score 3):

The `rules` prop of Vuetify's Text field component is expected to be an array:

> Vuetify includes simple validation through the rules prop. The prop accepts a mixed array of types `function`, `boolean` and `string`. When the input value changes, each element in the array will be validated. Functions pass the current v-model as an argument and must return either `true` / `false` or a `string` containing an error message.

See: [Text field component - Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields/#validation)

However, in your `parent`'s data, you define `rules` as an object with your validation functions (instead of an array that contains those functions):

```js
    rules: {
      required: (v) => !!v || "This field is required",
      autoComplete: (v) => !!(v && v.length) || "This field is required"
    }
```

If you change it to the following, it should work:

```js
    rules: [
      (v) => !!v || "This field is required",
      (v) => !!(v && v.length) || "This field is required"
    ]
```

Note that in both versions, you are declaring anonymous functions. If you want to keep the function name for reference, you could use named functions like so:

```js
    rules: [
      function required(v) { return !!v || "This field is required"; },
      function autoComplete(v) { return !!(v && v.length) || "This field is required"; }
    ]
```